# QDialog Window Mysteriously Launches After Exiting PyInstaller Frozen Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

A PyQt5 QDialog window is mysteriously and automatically launching after my frozen Python 3.8 script exits.

I have two different applications (ProgA and ProgB) created by freezing Python scripts.  They are similar in that they both have PyQt5 GUI interfaces, both incorporate video using OpenCV, both have similar QDialog windows used for user configurations, and both run on a Windows 10 platform.  Each application has multiple Python modules and each have been frozen with both PyInstaller and with cx_Freeze.

ProgA runs and exits without any issue when executed within the IDE or after freezing it with either PyInstaller or cx_Freeze.

ProgB runs and exits without any issues from within the IDE or after freezing with cx_Freeze.  ProgB also runs fine after freezing with PyInstaller ***but then something bizarre upon exit – a QDialog window containing user configurations is launched.***

This dialog window contains several radio buttons and QLineEdit object.  When  launched after the main window exits, the window is exactly as it is created in Qt Designer – it contains the default radio button checkmarks as if it was reset – it has none of the user configuration preferences.  Therefore, the config file is not being read.

I created a minimal example that exits the program exactly as ProgB, but the minimal example does not recreate the problem.

I also put print statements followed by 2-seconds of sleep (so I could follow execution) between every statement after the main window exit button is clicked.  ProbB executes the very last statement, `QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()` before the dialog window is launched.

Here is the spec file I’m using with PyInstaller.

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['ProgB.py','CustomCombo.py','Config.py','Layout.py'],
             pathex=['c:\\Users\\slalo\\Documents\\VTMBuild'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('Icon.ico','.'),
                    ('IconSmall.ico','.'),
                    ('License.txt','.'),
                    ('Manual.htm','.'),
                    ('Manual_files','Manual_files')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='ProgB',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='ProgB')
```

I am at my wits end.  I cannot find any reason the QDialog window should mysteriously appear after exiting ProgB.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any script in the `Analysis` list is treated as a main when PyInstaller packages the frozen baseline.  The supporting files (`CustomCombo.py`, `Config.py`, and `Layout.py`) should be included in the `datas` list instead of the `Analysis` list.  This solved my issue.